# my app is runing on android 5(api 22) but not work in android 4(api 16)

Tags: android, api, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

My Android App is good working on android 5 but when test app on other device(android 4) is crashing.
I did not use the special code.
Unfortunately my android studio is not have virtual device for api16 to see error log.
please help me.thanks

my gradle code:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blogsky.delete.azbook"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Install virtual device for API 16?

Comment: i am newcomer and can't(I do not know) install virtual device for api 16:(

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#viewing

Answer (score 0):

We can not know what make ur app crash without error log. Please install sdk 16 and setup virtual device, and post your error message here

Comment: thanks for your answer.i am install sdk 16 but not any virtual device (api 16) in avd.i do not know is add virtual devise for api 16. :(

Comment: Press AVD icon on your Android studio toolbar -> new virtual device -> and here you will have a list of api level here. Just keep going on those steps

Comment: thank you.but all device have api 23 and not any device (api 16) on list.

Comment: oh you missing image of a divce with api 16. on screen to select api, please go to x86 images tab or other image, please download images from here which is api 16, and go create again